# Connect to docker container started inside Gitlab docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

We have a Gitlab setup with Sysbox ([link to the setup](https://blog.nestybox.com/2020/10/21/gitlab-dind.html#gitlab-runner-deploys-jobs-in-system-containers)) to avoid running the docker executor on priviledged mode. Currently the `services` attribute works and we can communicate to it, but containers started with `dind` are inaccessible. Here's a minimal `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to reproduce the problem:

```yaml
docker_gitlab_test:
  stage: test
  image: docker:19.03.13
  tags:
    - docker # this is our docker executor
  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind
  script:
    - apk add curl
    - mkdir test
    - echo "hello world" > test/index.html
    - docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v $(pwd)/test:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro --hostname nginx --name nginx nginx
    - curl localhost:8080
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

The curl commands returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`. Running `nmap` says all ports are closed. I know this setup works with `privileged` docker executors. I've tried setting `--privileged` on the `docker run` command but to no avail. I've tried other base images other than `docker` but the problem persisted. I've tried running images other than `nginx` but the same problem happened.

How to allow the gitlab job to access containers running detached on `dind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`? Also, the `network_mode` property for the runner should be `host` (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html)

Comment: Using network_mode `host`, reconfiguring the ports, the container is accessible on the hostname `docker:8080`